# Histogram with ordinal data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram, data-visualization

I have dataset with colors and I want to show how many entries of each color I have in current dataset.

After formatting my dataset it is an array of strings:

```
const colors = [
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'red',
    'green'
]
```

I want to make a scale that I can feed into histogram layout. The scale should help layout to create a number of bins. After I feed data into histogram generator I expect to get an array with a 5 entries. Each object in array should has `x0` and `x1` property.

This is what I expect after reading a documentation. Btw, this is what I expect as my final result:

[image]

This is how my code looks like:

```
const width = container.node().getBoundingClientRect().width
const xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(colors).range([0, width])
const histogramGenerator = d3.histogram()

histogramGenerator
  .domain(xScale.domain())
  .tresholds(xScale.domain().length)

const histogramData = histogramGenerator(colors)
```

Actual result looks:

```
[Array(0)]
  0: [x0: "red", x1: "blue"]
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

I don't want to use bar chart, the whole reason of this experiment is to learn how to use d3 histogram with ordinal data like this colors dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately a *"histogram with ordinal data"* is, by definition, impossible. What you want is a **bar chart** instead. Quoting the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) about histogram,

> A histogram is an accurate representation of the distribution of numerical data. It is an estimate of the probability distribution of a **continuous variable** and was first introduced by Karl Pearson.

The emphasis on **continuous variable** is mine.

If you look at `d3.histogram` [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/ce9507c360c3a016eb3f015ff2bc68909674c381/src/bin.js#L53) (now renamed as `d3.bin`), you'll see that it expect numerical values:

```
// Assign data to bins by value, ignoring any outside the domain.
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  x = values[i];
  if (x0 <= x && x <= x1) {
    bins[bisect(tz, x, 0, m)].push(data[i]);
  }
}
```

Have a look at `x0 <= x && x <= x1` specifically.

I can see that you wrote *"I don't want to use bar chart, the whole reason of this experiment is to learn how to use d3 histogram"*. In that case, chose the **correct data**, that is, a dataset with a continuous variable instead.

#### Solution for a bar chart:

All that being said, ditch that histogram generator and create a good old bar chart. For that to work, all you'll need is manipulating tour data. For instance, let's use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an array of objects, with `colour` and `count`.

Suppose this data array:

```
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'pink', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green'];
```

We can manipulate it like this:

```js
const colors = [
  'red',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'red',
  'red',
  'green',
  'yellow',
  'pink',
  'red',
  'green',
  'yellow',
  'pink',
  'pink',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'green',
  'green',
  'green',
  'green'
];

const data = colors.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const foundObject = acc.find(e => e.colour === curr);
  if (foundObject) ++foundObject.count;
  else acc.push({
    colour: curr,
    count: 1
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(data)
```

Now you can use this data array to create your bar chart, with `colours` as the categorical variable in the `x` axis, and `count` as the quantitative variable in the `y` axis.